# ipv6 tunnel in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: server, ipv6, tunnel, netplan

I used to be able to do the configuration below with no issues in `/etc/network/interfaces` but now it's not picked up anymore. How do I configure a ipv6 tunnel now? I see see the new netplan software to configure interfaces but I can't seem to find the equivalent commands to the ones below

```
auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
        address 2001:550:120e:6b7::2
        netmask 64
        endpoint 184.105.253.10
        local my.public.ip.addr
        ttl 255
        gateway 2001:550:120e:6b7::1
```

How do I configure Ubuntu to keep this configuration permanently on the next reboot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out.

I created the following files:

**/etc/systemd/network/he-ipv6.network**

```
[Match]

[Network]
Tunnel=he-ipv6
```

**/etc/systemd/network/he-ipv6-tunnel.netdev**

```
[Match]                                                                                                                                                                                                            

[NetDev]                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Name=he-ipv6                                        
Kind=sit                                            

[Tunnel]
Independent=true                                            
Local=192.168.0.x #Private IP if behind NAT or Public IP without NAT                                   
Remote=184.105.250.46 #Tunnel broker's IPv4 address                         
TTL=255
```

**/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml**

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
      he-ipv6:
          dhcp4: no
          dhcp6: no
          addresses: ['2001:470:xxx:xxx::2/64']
          gateway6: 2001:470:xxx:xxx::1
      enp0s3:
      ...
```

Where `2001:470:xxx:xxx::2/64` is your Client IP address from tunnelbroker.net

Then reboot or restart your network with `systemctl restart systemd-networkd && netplan apply`

**Update/Warning** This won't work unless you're already using Ubuntu Bionic Beaver or specifically speaking Systemd Version 235. [You **need** the `Independent` flag under [Tunnel] for this configuration to work on every reboot along with systemd version 235](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992919/what-does-the-sign-mean-after-a-tunnel-interface/992945#992945).

The `Independent` flag doesn't work in systemd version 234 and below. You can check your systemd version with `systemd --version`

Comment: Any specific reason to use `Independent=` instead of adding something like:  

`[Network]
Tunnel=he-ipv6`

In a new file `/etc/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.network.d/tunnel.conf` ?

Comment: I'm adding tunnel support in netplan. It will work soon in the development release, and once it's there we'll make it available for 18.04 and above.

Comment: @MathieuTrudel-Lapierre Please post a full example in a new answer so that others may see how to do it that way.

Comment: No point in adding the answer until that's actually released anywhere :) Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 22.04 Lts this is very simple because netplan has built-in 4to6 sit tunnel support.
For example for tunneling to Hurricane Tunnel Broker Paris from Oracle Cloud (behind Oracle NAT).
Create /etc/netplan/60-tunnel-he-ipv6.yaml

```yml
network:
  version: 2
  tunnels:
    he-ipv6:
      mode: sit
      remote: 216.66.84.42           #HE Paris ip4 enpoint   
      local: 10.0.0.242              #local ipv4 address (mine is behind nat)
      addresses:
        - "2001:470:001:002::2/64"   #your ipv6 endpoint
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: "2001:470:001:002::1" #HE Tunnel ipv6 endpoint
```

next simply issue

```sh
sudo netplan try
```

And accept configuration if there is no error

Comment: Now if we can only get around Netflix blocking HE Tunnels :(

Comment: @Tek for avoiding having a bad ipv6 reputation ask the main IP geolocalion providers (ex Maxmind for geoip) to set your prefix to your physical location. it is easy. Check https://www.iplocation.net/ip-lookup with you HE prefix

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
modprobe ipv6
ip tunnel add he-ipv6 mode sit remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx local xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ttl 255
ip link set he-ipv6 up
ip addr add 2001:470:1f10:d47::2/64 dev he-ipv6
ip route add ::/0 dev he-ipv6
ip -f inet6 addr
```

From a root shell, and cut & paste the command block.
The modprobe makes sure that the kernel has ipv6 support loaded.
The "ip tunnel ..." creates a point to point tunnel, using the outside IPv4 address of your NAT router/firewall/modem as the local side and the selected relay as the remote side, where the relaying will happen.
The "ip link ..." should be self-explanatory; it turns the tunnel on.
The "ip addr add ..." configures the IPv6 address your host is using.
The "ip route add" configures a default v6 route pointing at the tunnel, so that any v6-traffic headed to the general internet will know where to go.

> SOURCE: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1700452

Comment: Yes but this configuration would be lost upon reboot. Where do I configure this to keep it permanently?

Comment: Make a sh script from it an run it on startup