# What does the @ sign mean after a tunnel interface?

Tags: networking, ipv6, tunnel, ipv4

I previously asked a question on setting up a ipv4 to ipv6 tunnel.

I answered my own question and this is configuration output from my previous question here https://askubuntu.com/a/992872/13903

```
4: he-ipv6@lo: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65516 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 47.x.x.x peer 216.66.77.230
    inet6 2001:470:7b:616::2/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2fbb:2226/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However this has a `@lo` suffix next to `he-ipv6`. It looks right but it does not let me ping ipv6 address such as ipv6.google.com

I tried the same configuration with `ip` linux tools.

```
ip tunnel add he-ipv6 mode sit remote 216.66.77.230 local 47.x.x.x ttl 255
ip addr add 2001:470:7b:616::2/64 dev he-ipv6
ip route add ::/0 dev he-ipv6
```

Which got me the interface he-ipv6 with suffix `@NONE`. This configuration **does** work and this is the output I get:

```
5: he-ipv6@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 47.x.x.x peer 216.66.77.230
    inet6 2001:470:7b:616::2/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c0a8:1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What is the @ symbol mean next to the tunneling interface?

How can I change my configuration in my [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990195/ipv6-tunnel-in-ubuntu-17-10/992872#992872) to avoid getting the `@lo` suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to answer my own question again after some lenghty research! So according to this [systemd.netdev manual](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2017-October/039589.html) I need the independent flag for my configuration to work.

> Independent= A boolean. When true tunnel does not require .network
>   file. Created as "tunnel@NONE". Defaults to "false".

However this isn't available until [systemd announcement version 235](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2017-October/039589.html).

Running command `systemd --version` it seems I'm running systemd version 234.

Systemd  version 235 isn't available until [Ubuntu Bionic Beaver](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd)

After switching all the strings in `/etc/apt/sources.list` from `artful` to `bionic`

Running `apt-update` and `sudo apt install --only-upgrade systemd`

I switched back again `bionic` to `artful` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and doing an `sudo apt update && sudo reboot`.

Then I was finally able to get the `Independent` flag to work in my `[Tunnel]` systemd configuration which let me ping ipv6.google.com on every reboot! I'm a happy camper :)