# netplan gre tunnel+quagga

Tags: netplan, tunnel

After installing new router with ubuntu 18.04 on it i'm got a problem with working ospf via gre tunnel to my older routers.
All configured simular, but from new router i got ospf state Init/DROther. Older routers (without netplan) dont see any neighbor.
Tunnels work fine with static routing.

I found solution and fix problem manually. I found that netplan make tunnel with 'ttl inherit' (on other routers ttl 255).

> tunnel1: gre/ip remote 1.1.1.1 local 2.2.2.2 ttl inherit

After `ip tunnel change tunnel1 ttl 255` command execution ospf starts to work.

How can I add to netplan ttl and pointopoint parameters to tunnel intarface? 
How to set commands like below to netplan file?

```
ifconfig tunnel1 pointopoint 10.2.2.1
ip tunnel change tunnel1 ttl 255
```

Comment: If you fixed your issue, don't put a solution inside of a question. Answer your question and accept your answer in two days.

Comment: i'm looking for issue, i can't add this to netplan. So after reboot i need to use some crutch. Run fixing command in rc.local or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

netplan currently lacks the ability to configure the `ttl` / `hoplimit` of a tunnel. This issue has been brought up in its issue tracker ([bug #1846783](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1846783)), however its developers seem to have not paid attention to this.

Meanwhile you can configure the tunnel using connection managers that support setting this field such as systemd-networkd and NetworkManager, or try to run a script that calls `ip tunnel` after the tunnel has been brought up by netplan.

You might also be interested in the workaround described in the original feature request for supporting IP tunnels in [bug #1799487](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1799487), or [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/a/992872/1000084) on this site