# How do I setup an IPv6 tunnel?

Tags: networking, 20.04, vps

I have a ubuntu 20.04 VPS. I want to setup an IPv6 tunnel. So I went to tunnelbroker.net and created a new tunnel. However, it tells me to  paste something into /etc/network/interfaces. When I looked in my server, I dont seem to have that file. So, where do I paste the configuration to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ipv6 tunnel in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990195/ipv6-tunnel-in-ubuntu-17-10)